# Google sheets dropdown lists that update as options get seleected

Tags: google-apps-script, dynamic, dropdown, google-forms, multiple-choice

Hi all I’m just starting to look at google forms and sheets.

I’m wanting to create a form to vote for players in a team.

I dont want to use the multiple choice style of question, I want to use dropdown lists.

I’d like 3-5 dropdowns eg: “3 Votes”, “2 Votes”, “1 Vote”,  “1 Vote”,  “1 Vote”. All of these dropdown lists draw from the one sheet with the team members and would all have the same 20 odd names displayed on activation. 
However, when a player is selected in “3votes” it would not appear in “2votes” or “1vote” dropdown lists, and so on, as players are selected in the 2vote and 1vote lists.

The intent is to remove the opportunity to vote for a player more than once

The form will be used by a number of people that could vote the same way,so it’s not like removing appointment options for everyone, just what the form can select as it’s being used

I can do it with multi choice radio buttons without any scripting, but it’s not very elegant esp on a phone.

I image this is a relatively simple script, but I have no idea about JavaScript or gs.

Thanks for help in advance
Eddie

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO isn't a place where people will write the code for you. If you show effort, we can provide guidance.

Comment: Interacting with Google Forms as you have requested is not possible. However, it can be accomplished with JavaScript , html and a web app. Although that will limit the number simultaneous users to about 30.